# Unicode notation of Euler Constant

Tags: notation, euler-mascheroni-constant

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), [eulers-constant](/questions/tagged/eulers-constant) is usually denoted as $\gamma$.  Why does [Unicode](https://unicode-table.com/en/2107/) use 'ℇ' to denote this number?

Wikipedia redirects ['ℇ'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%84%87) to [eulers-constant](/questions/tagged/eulers-constant), but in that page, there's *no* mention of Unicode.

Are both notation accepted?  Which one is better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[One conversation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AEuler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant#%E2%84%87_(U+2107_EULER_CONSTANT)) about the symbol on the talk page corresponding to the [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) for Euler's constant on Wikipedia led me to [another](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AEuler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant#Symbol_for_Eulers_constant) where the link you discovered was first put into place. That other discussion also gave the clue that this is related to an old Xerox standard "XCCS 353/046". Searching for that, led me to an archive of [a conversation about Unicode back in 2002](http://unicode.org/mail-arch/unicode-ml/y2002-m04/0073.html) where Ken Whistler, [a technical director for Unicode](http://unicode.org/consortium/directors.html) said the following:

> The source for this 
>   character is XCCS 353/046 "Euler's". That Xerox standard didn't 
>   say Euler's *what*, however. And the character committees just 
>   added "CONSTANT" to it.

So, to summarize:

- For reasons unknown (I can't find any more detail online), an old Xerox standard had a table of characters with something like ℇ on it labeled "Euler's"
- Early Unicode committee(s) thought it might be distinct from other forms of "E", and figured it was some constant of Euler's so made ℇ and labeled it "Euler Constant". But it's unclear whether they had in mind [Euler's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) $e$ or [the Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) $\gamma$.
- Someone editing Wikipedia, having in mind the sometimes-followed convention that "Euler's constant" is $\gamma$ and not $e$, decided to make ℇ link to the page for $\gamma$.
- That was never undone, despite the facts that: As far as I can tell, *no one* uses ℇ for $\gamma$. Since ℇ looks like $E$ or $\varepsilon$, that suggests $e$ is more likely than $\gamma$ as the original intent of the Xerox standard.